# Ingresar datos desde consulta .sql a tabla por partes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos adjuntada dinamicamente a mi proyecto asp.net mvc, con 12 columnas por llenar con datos de prueba, al no encontrar un software que me genere exactamente en orden los datos que requiero y los limites de cada uno como edad, nombres, fechas, etc. Considero que una forma manual de resolver este problema es llenar columna por columna con datos de prueba que sean faciles de generar, y los datos mas especificos como fechas o apellidos ir extrayendolo de otras bases de datos.

mi problema:
Agregue 1 columna de 1000 datos y quedaron NULL las demas columnas, al yo querer llenar la columna 2 con sus respectivos 1000 datos ¿como podria indicarle a la BD que me coloque esos datos en registros ya existentes pero incompletos o con espacio NULL? espero se me pueda entender.

- intente pero crea nuevos registros con la columna 1 vacia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta tabla la creaste vos desde sql server?

Comment: SI creado desde sql server y lo lleve  como base dinamica dentro de mi proyecto y por eso indicaba, que solo puedo hacer consultas sobre las tablas desde el proyecto.

Comment: perdón pero no entiendo bien. como que solo podes consultar?, deberías poder modificar los datos. Sino es difícil completar los datos faltantes. o se podría hacer en memoria con una consulta... pero no seria lo optimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En SQL Server se puede consultar qué columnas tienen NULL, con una consulta del estilo

```sql
SELECT * FROM [MiTabla] WHERE [fechaingreso] IS NULL;
```

Para actualizar los registros que tienen NULL, la condición es la misma:

```sql
UPDATE [MiTable] SET [fechaingreso] = '2016/03/10' WHERE [fechaingreso] IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `rand()` para generar datos aleatorios

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(700), `description` varchar(550))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (rand() *1000, concat('name' , rand()*1000), concat('des', rand()*1000)),
    (rand() *1000, concat('name' , rand()*1000), concat('des', rand()*1000)),
    (rand() *1000, concat('name' , rand()*1000), concat('des', rand()*1000)),
    (rand() *1000, concat('name' , rand()*1000), concat('des', rand()*1000))
;
```

Y vamos a tener algo asi

```
productName           | description
name530.7602607931572 | des890.7861578192433
name635.8917445278651 | des594.5086410217999
name540.8141189634932 | des509.46661877396207
name96.05401297663713 | des705.5977924779037
```

Aqui esta el [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f0568/1).

Este metodo casi te asegura tener valores no duplicados